# What is the difference of defining a global var in server/ and in private/?

Tags: meteor

For example, I want to insert some init json data into db when Meteor startup. And I have two ways.

**1. define it in server/init.js**

```
server/data.js:
data1 = [{ "data": "to insert"}];
server/init.js
Meteor.startup(function() { insertToDb(data1); });
```

**2. define it in private/data.json**

```
private/data.json
[{ "data": "to insert"}];
server/init.js
Meteor.startup(function() { 
  var data2 =  Assets.getText("data.json");
  insertToDb(data2); 
});
```

A. Does `data1` live all the time? If so, if data is big, it would waste some memory?

B. What is the cons and pros?

C. The general purpose or scenario of `private`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has little to do with whether you are loading data from a file or defining it statically and more to do with your data variable scope. If you define something globally then yes, it will be stored in memory for the lifetime of the process. If you define it locally within a function then  once the function exits, all memory is freed.

For instance, you can do this:

server/init.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() { 
  var data1 = [{ "data": "to insert"}];
  insertToDb(data1);
});
```

With that said, here is an opinion if you so desire to read it:
Logically, any big block of data should not be statically defined. Save it in a separate file so it is easy to update. An example of this is localization files.